# Is a good pattern to save different types of data in one NoSQL table?

Tags: nosql

I am looking for NoSQL database design pattern. I found there are many cases people save different types of data in one table. For example, `product` and `order` are two different data.  They can be saved in one table with a `type` field to differentiate the data.

```
{ 
  name: 'product.xxx',
  type: 'PRODUCT',
  ...
},
{
  name: 'order.xxx',
  type: 'ORDER',
  ..
}
```

In above example, a product and an order are saved in one table with different format. And the `type` field is used to differentiate them. And we can build an index on the `type` for querying performance. I wonder is this a popular pattern in NoSQL? What is the benefits on doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Not only is this a common pattern, it's the desired way to use DynamoDB.  From the [Amazon NoSQL Design Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html#bp-general-nosql-design-concepts):

> As a general rule, you should maintain as few tables as possible in a DynamoDB application.

Why would this be?  Why would you want to keep data representing so many entities in fewer tables?  Why do many people strive to use a *single* table?  The answer comes down to performance.

DynamoDB is built for speed at scale.  Ideally, many of your application access patterns can be implemented with a single query to DynamoDB.  In order to do this, we 1) have to fit everything into one table and 2) store our data in a way that supports our access patterns.

The second point is easier said than done if you are coming from a relational DB/SQL background.  DynamoDB is *totally* different, so leave that DB knowledge at the door when you start learning about DynamoDB.  For example, DynamoDB does not support join operations, which makes having your data stored across multiple tables less appealing.

There's a ton written about this topic and I've only just scratched the surface of "Why?".  But to answer your question: yes, it's quite common and desirable to have multiple entities in a single table when using DynamoDB.

Here is a [great blog post](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-single-table/#the-solution-pre-join-your-data-into-item-collections) describing why in greater detail (with examples).

Comment: From that blog post "The main reason for using a single table in DynamoDB is to retrieve multiple, heterogenous item types using a single request."   If you can't or don't need to, then a single table provides more trouble than benefit.